# Using DISTINCT in Excel Data Model

Tags: excel, duplicates, dax, distinct, datamodel

I am using Excel Data Model where I have imported some data from an SQL Query. I am trying to do the excel equivalent of removing duplicates in a column.

So I saw the DISTINCT function exists and says: "Returns a one column table that contains the distinct (unique) values in a column, for a column argument."

That is exactly what I need, I have a column which has 2million rows but only about 4k distinct values/rows.

However when I go into the Calculation area and create the `measure_distinct:=DISTINCT(TABLE_NAME[COLUMN_NAME])` it gives the following error: "*Calculation error in measure 'TABLE_NAME'[measure_distinct]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected*"

I get that what I am trying to get is not a measure, it's a one column table and I probably shouldn't be using the DISTINCT function in the Calculation area. But I cannot figure out where or how to use it in order to get that column with unique values.

**The objective is to import that column of distinct values into the Excel sheet.**

Any help is greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: You should be using Power Query for this, not Power Pivot.

Comment: UNIQUE() works in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, this should really be done in Power Query. However, it can also be done using DAX.

You need to import a random table using Data/Existing Connections and then selecting one of the available tables, choosing 'Table' in the Import Dialog box.

Then, right-click in this table, select 'Table/Edit DAX', then 'DAX' in the Command Type dropdown and type this in the Expression box:

`EVALUATE DISTINCT(TABLE_NAME[COLUMN_NAME])`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is more than enough to get me started and exactly what I was looking for.

I am also more than happy to use Power Query, how should I do it there?

Comment: Just create a new query from your current table, remove other columns and remove duplicates then load to the worksheet.